# I get my certificate from a HTTPConnection call and save in trust managers, but webView needs SSL not X509 Certificate, is it possible to convert?

Tags: android, ssl, webview, https, certificate

I have a HTTPConnection call And I do this on it:

```
 if(conn != null && conn.getServerCertificates() != null) {
        Utils.appendLog("Entered Logic to add certificates",false);
        Certificate ca = conn.getServerCertificates()[0];
        Log.i("","adding certificate is: " + ca.getPublicKey().toString());
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        InputStream readStream = new FileInputStream(c.getFilesDir() + "/VidyoRemote/keystore.jks");
        String pass = "Ready4Launch!";
        try{
            keyStore.load(readStream, pass.toCharArray());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("","error trying to load:" + e.getMessage());
            keyStore.load(null, pass.toCharArray());
        }
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(c.getFilesDir() + "/VidyoRemote/keystore.jks");
        keyStore.store(fos, pass.toCharArray());
        fos.close();
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    }
```

Saving the x509 certificate inside.
But then I need to use a webview to connec to that IP.
I get an SSL error with a SSL Certificate. How can I check this SSL certificate to the X509 that I have saved?
My OnReceivedSslError:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
        Log.i("","ssl certificate is: " + error.getCertificate());
        Log.i("","ssl certificate is: " + error.getCertificate().getIssuedBy().toString());
        Log.i("","ssl certificate is: " + error.getCertificate().getIssuedTo().toString());
        Log.i("","ssl certificate is: " + error.getCertificate().getValidNotAfterDate().toString());
        c = new ContextWrapper(context);
        Utils.appendLog("received SSL error on webview: "+ + error.getPrimaryError() + " on certificate: " + error.getCertificate(), false);
        try{
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            InputStream readStream = new FileInputStream(c.getFilesDir() + "/VidyoRemote/keystore.jks");
            String pass = "Ready4Launch!";
            try{
                keyStore.load(readStream, pass.toCharArray());
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("","error trying to load check:" + e.getMessage());
                keyStore.load(null, pass.toCharArray());
            }
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);
            for (TrustManager trustManager : tmf.getTrustManagers()){
                X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
                for (X509Certificate certificate : x509TrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers()){
                    Log.i("","certificate is: " + certificate.toString());
                    Log.i("","certificate is: " + certificate.getSerialNumber());
                    Log.i("","certificate is: " + certificate.getSignature());
                    Log.i("","certificate is: " + certificate.getVersion());
                    Log.i("","certificate is: " + certificate.getPublicKey());
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("","Error is: " + e.getMessage());
        }
//        handler.proceed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this:

```
  for (TrustManager trustManager : tmf.getTrustManagers()){
            X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManager;
            for (X509Certificate certificate : x509TrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers()){
                Log.i("","certificate is: " + certificate.getIssuerX500Principal().getName());
                if(error.getCertificate().toString().contains(certificate.getIssuerX500Principal().getName())){
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            }
        }
```

certificate.getIssuerX500Principal().getName() being contained in the SSL Certificate